# How to get all columns in PostgreSQL along with CONCATing two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

So i am joining these two tables A and B
B contains  first_name and last_name
So i am writing query like this

```
select col1,col2,...,col12,CONCAT(first_name,last_name) as NAME 
from A 
  INNER JOIN B on A.email=B.email;
```

Now i want all columns from this query but instead of writing all column names...are there any ways to get every column along with concatenation of these two **first_name** and **last_name**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*`

```
select *, CONCAT(first_name,last_name) as NAME 
from A 
  INNER JOIN B on A.email=B.email;
```

If you want to get the join column only once, you can use:

```
select *, CONCAT(first_name,last_name) as NAME 
from A 
  INNER JOIN B using (email);
```

Comment: can we get all columns along with join but except for column3?

Comment: @HarshilSharaf: no, that's not possible (unless you explicitly write every column you want)